# how to insert on duplicate key update into mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have table which is related to another table. i need to insert ids and update on duplicate key insertion. below is the query i am inserting into table but giving syntax error. multiple rows will be inserted like
(88, 90709), (88, 90710),  ..

```
 Error Number: 1064

 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds     to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use     near '90713), business_id= VALUES(88)' at line 3

INSERT INTO business_service_coverage (business_id, area_id) VALUES (88,90713) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE area_id = VALUES(90713), business_id= VALUES(88)
```

Table structure

```
 1) id  primary key auto increment
 2) busienss_id not unique
 3) area_id int
```

Comment: In the update part you dont need to wrap the values in 'VALUES()'

Answer (score 0):

Your [syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is wrong as specified,Try the below

```
INSERT INTO business_service_coverage (business_id, area_id) VALUES (88,90713) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE area_id = 90713, business_id= 88;
```